# Problem with modal window in Ajax & Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, modal-dialog

I am trying to make my modal window in my first Django project (I don't know JS and I started in Django) and I put a JS function on my modal window click.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function () {
  $(".js-create-articles").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/articles/create/',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-articles").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-articles .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```
class MainArticles(ListView):
template_name = 'dishes/articles.html'
model = Articles
```

class MainArticlesCreate(View):

```
def get(self, request):
    form = ArticlesForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    html_form = render_to_string('dishes/articles_create.html',
                                 context,
                                 request=request,
                                 )
    return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})

class ArticlesForm(forms.ModelForm):
model = Articles
fields = {'name', 'tag', 'deception'}

class Articles(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tag = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
deception = models.TextField(max_length=800)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block javascript %}
<script src="{% static 'js/articles.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section class="feature">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2 class="section-header">Товары в корзине</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-create-articles">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    New article
                </button>
            </p>
            <table class="table">
                <tr class="info">
                    <td class="info col-md-3">Товар</td>
                </tr>
                {% for obj in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="info col-md-3">{{ obj.name }}</td>
                    <td class="info col-md-3">{{ obj.deception }}</td>
                    <td class="info col-md-3">
                        <button>edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                {% empty %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" class="text-center bg-warning">No book</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <p><a href="{% url 'dishes:index' %}">NAZAAAAAD </a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- THE MODAL  -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-articles">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% load widget_tweaks %}


<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new articles</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Clicking on the button works, I checked the alert but the window does not work or if it works, I just don’t see it. What am I missing?

Comment: take a look at this article https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

Comment: I'm working on it. and at the stage as we have a modal window, it does not appear